# Spring Boot: What is the Right Way to Implement Basic Auth with httpheaders

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am consuming a secured Restful Service that grants access through Basic Auth (Username and Password). I have successfully accessed the  API service and consumed its API; however, I am still confused as to what is the right way to implement  HTTP headers with Basic Auth. I would assume I should authenticate only once, but the way I have constructed my code, it looks like I need to authenticate API with each service method I create.

Should I create a helper method with the authentication and call it on each service?

Comment: Does the question relate to the development of the secure API or more the correct way you should consume an API with basic auth?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Basic Auth you need to **always** include credentials with your request.  In case of OAuth, tokens have expiry. In this case, a token caching mechanism for the duration of a little bit less than the expiration duration would do the trick.

Comment: Yes, I am using Basic Auth. You are saying for every single API call I am doing, I need to include credentials with the request?

Comment: @Zeusox, yes. With basic auth, you must include credentials with every request.

Comment: Actually, with every HTTP authentication system you need to include something with the request. HTTP is a request-response protocol. Every request is independant from the previous ones. So every request needs to include something that allows the server to know who sent it.

Answer (score 1):

The **Basic Auth** is a kind of **no status** authentication. That means the server wouldn't record. Every time you need to provide **username** and **password** with your request. Each request is equal to the Server.

For another authentication called **OAuth**, the first time you request with username and password, the server will return a **token** to the frontend, which has an expiration period. So, you request every time with the token through the filter, where checks the expiry of the token. If it's not expired, using the same token for requests, otherwise, making a request to get another token.